# SonarQube 5.4 SCM Stats plugin?

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to get commit and author details for a project in sonarqube.
I see [scm stats](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/SCM+Stats+Plugin) plugin does it for prior versions.
I am using the latest version sonarqube 5.4.

Is there any way we can use `scm stats plugin` for `sonarqube 5.4` or any alternative that i can use?.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new SCM functionality offered by SonarQube and no need for SCM plugins.

Go to Administration -- > on left hand side you will see "SCM" option.

For my team , we were looking for SCM report but unfortunately its not available ,so we are using web API to generate it by own.